# android html font size according to screen density

Tags: android, html, android-screen

I need a way to say if device is LDPI or MDPI or HDPI set html font size to x.
e.g

```
if (ldpi){
htmlString.append("<br><p align='center'><font color='Yellow' size='5'>");
}
else if (mdpi){
htmlString.append("<br><p align='center'><font color='Yellow' size='6'>");
}
else if (hdpi){
htmlString.append("<br><p align='center'><font color='Yellow' size='7'>");
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

you can get dpi value like this;

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

and compare the `density` property with constants;

```
int DENSITY_DEFAULT The reference density used throughout the system.
int DENSITY_HIGH    Standard quantized DPI for high-density screens.
int DENSITY_LOW Standard quantized DPI for low-density screens.
int DENSITY_MEDIUM  Standard quantized DPI for medium-density screens.
int DENSITY_TV  Standard quantized DPI for 720p TV screens.
int DENSITY_XHIGH
```